# Conditional expression

Tags: c

so I'm studying for my exam and I do not understand how can I solve this conditional expression. I know that if the expression 1 is true, I do the expression 2, and if it is false, I do the expression 3. Can someone help me understanding what I need to do in the first expression?

```
int A = -1, B = -2, C = -3;
int X = 1;
(X = B != C) ? (A = (~C) - A--) : (++C + (~A));
printf(" A = %d  B = %d  C = %d  X = %d\n", A, B, C, X);
```

Comment: Do you know what operators like `~` and `++` do?

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes I do. How does the 1st expression work tho? X = -2 != -3?? I can't understand

Comment: @Marco It's time for you to dig out your operator precedence tables.

Comment: know your [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Specifically note that `A = (~C) - A--` is not valid code (trying to change `A` twice), so we cannot expect any specific result.

Comment: In the first section of the ternary, it is TRUE that `B != C`, so `X` evaluates to 1, meaning execution flows to the the _true_ section of the ternary.  But this results in executing code that doesn't make sense.

Comment: The only good, rather than required, answer is to not use such compound expressions and instead, split them up and use temporary boolean vars to hold the intermediate results.  If you look at an expression for more than ten seconds and cannot understand how it works and/or how to debug it, split it up.

Comment: Good luck with your exam.  If this question is representative of the ones you're likely to see on it, you're going to *need* some luck.  (This may be one of those times where you have a choice between passing your exam, or learning C, because whatever it is that the exam is testing, it has little to do with actually knowing C well. Certainly the expression in this question has very little to do with knowing C well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of the program is undefined.

`(X = B != C)` is grouped as `(X = (B != C))` and is 1 since `B` is not equal to `C`.

A *sequencing point* is passed over (not relevant here but you can be confident that `X` is 1 when one of the ternary branches are evaluated), and the "true" branch of the ternary conditional is evaluated. But the behaviour of the expression `(A = (~C) - A--)` is *undefined*. And that puts the whole program into an undefined state including, somewhat bizarrely, any statements that have already ran.